# Embedded iframe in WebBrowser Control not loading

Tags: c#, iframe, embed, webbrowser-control

I have the following code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");

string _embeddedpage = "<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"black\"><iframe height=\"300\" width=\"600\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0\"></iframe></body></html>";

webBrowser1.Document.Write(_embeddedpage);
```

Unfortunately no matter what I try the iframe doesn't load. The HTML works fine if I save it out to a HTML file and then run it, and it also works fine if i then point the webBrowser control at the physical html file.

However when doing it like this and creating the HTML from within the application it just won't play ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried it myself. This code will work for you:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string _embeddedpage = @"
            <html>
                <body>
                    <iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='640' height='385'
                        src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0\' frameborder='0'>
                    </iframe>
                </body>
            <html>";

    webBrowser1.DocumentText = _embeddedpage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition between loading "about:blank" and writing into the document.

You should write after the page has loaded, e.g. from `Navigated` event handler.